# How to fuse the informations of two lines, if pattern matches two lines?

Tags: awk

I would like to fuse the information of two lines, if the coordinates in the 2nd and 3rd column overlap and the 1st column is identical.

Input:

```
chr1    2   29  tcttttcagtgtctttagatgtgtact,
chr1    30  55  agcacatgattagaagctaccaatgg,
chr1    33  58  acatgattagaagctaccaatggccc,
chr2    30  52  ctaggcttacagaagtgagccc,
```

Output:

```
chr1    2   29  tcttttcagtgtctttagatgtgtact,
chr1    30  58  agcacatgattagaagctaccaatggccc,
chr2    30  52  ctaggcttacagaagtgagccc,
```

The second row of the output cover the span of the 2nd and 3rd row from the input, starting by 30 (from 2nd row) up to 58 (from 3rd row) (when the condition is true, that the coordinates overlap and the 1st column ist equal).
Each coordinate is linked to the correspondent letter of the 4th column. For the 2nd row of the input:

```
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 ... 50 51 52 53 54 55
a  g  c  a  c  a  t  ... c  a  a  t  g  g
```

So if the coordinate are fused, the information of the 4th column should be also fused. In this case three letters were added at the end:

```
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 ... 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58
a  g  c  a  c  a  t  ... c  a  a  t  g  g  c  c  c
```

I tried to subtract the 2nd column every 2 lines from each other and removed lines containing a similar value in the 2nd column. But i don't know how to fuse the information.

`awk 'NR-1{print $2-p}{p=$2}1' input.txt | paste - - | awk '($5>BiggerAs || $5<-SmallerAs)'`

Comment: Thank you for showing your efforts, could you please explain more on your Logic part in your question, its not much clear as of now IMHO.

Comment: what's the logic to **combine** `agcacatgattagaagctaccaatg` and `acatgattagaagctaccaatgccc,` into `agcacatgattagaagctaccaatgccc,` ?  are the contents of `input.txt` already sorted by columns 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Yes the columns are sorted by ```sort -k1,3´´´

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd column describe die position of an information on the chromosome from column 1. In the 4th column is the information stored. For example in the 2nd row: the 63095765 position on chromosome 1 is an 'a', the next position 63095766 is a 'g', ... . If the coordinates overlap i would like to remove both lines and create a new row, which start with the lowest position of the overlap and end with the highest position, including the sorted information of the 4th column.

Comment: Unclear how you are getting `agcacatgattagaagctaccaatgccc`

Comment: yeah, was just figuring that out; that makes sense for the 1st and 4th line, but the 2nd and 3rd lines are missing a character (the difference between columns 2 & 3 = 24 - for both lines, but column 4 contains 25 characters); you'll want to update the question with those additional details (not everyone is going to peruse the comments trying to piece together the whole picture)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I have updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions and collection of details from OP's comments:

- columns 2/3 are the begin/end indices (respectively) representing a substring from a chromosome sequence
- column 4 is the actual substring from the chromosome sequence
- data is already sorted
- objective is to merge substrings where the associated indices overlap (eg, in OP's sample data we need to merge lines 2 and 3)
- if overlapping substrings have different values in the same position, the first value will be captured/stored as the 'correct' value (ie, we are not going to validate that overlapping positions are identical)

Approach:

- use values in columns 2/3 as indices into a sparse array where each array element is a single letter
- for overlapping substrings we add to the array those positions/letters not already seen

Using OP's original sample data set:

```
$ cat input.txt
chr1    196308345   196308372   tcttttcagtgtctttagatgtgtact,
chr1    63095765    63095788    agcacatgattagaagctaccaatg
chr1    63095768    63095791    acatgattagaagctaccaatgccc,
chr2    63095768    63095789    ctaggcttacagaagtgagcc,
```

One `awk` solution:

```
awk '

function print_seq()                                        # function to print the merged data
{
  if ( seqend == 0 )                                        # make sure we have something to print; "seqend == 0" => we haven't processed any data, yet
     return

  printf "%-7s %-11s %-11s ", prev1, seqstart, seqend       # print first 3 columns

  for (i in myseq)                                          # print merged substring
      printf "%s",myseq[i]

  printf ",\n"                                              # print trailing comma + linefeed
}

function reset_ends()                                       # function to reset our start/end indices
{
  seqstart = 2^PREC
  seqend   = 0
}

BEGIN         { reset_ends() }                              # (re)set our indices

# if field 1 has changed or columns 2 & 3 are outside the previously seen index range then
# print the last substring and reset some variables

prev1 != $1 ||
$2 > seqend ||
$3 < seqstart { print_seq()                                 # print the last seq ...
                reset_ends()                                # reset our indices ...
                delete myseq                                # delete array containing last overlapping substring ...
                prev1=$1                                    # reset our "previous field 1" tracker
              }

# process a new, or overlapping, substring

              { seqstart = $2 < seqstart ? $2 : seqstart    # new/lesser sequence start?
                seqend   = $3 > seqend   ? $3 : seqend      # new/greater sequence end?
                j=$2                                        # initial index for myseq[] array

                gsub(",","",$4)                             # remove commas (eg, trailing comma)
                n=split($4,arr,"")                          # split column 4 into array of single-letter elements; "n" == number of elements in array

                for (i=1; i<=n; i++)                        # loop through our new set of letters
                    if ( j in myseq )                       # if we have already seen a letter for position "j" ...
                       j++                                  # increment j otherwise ...
                    else
                       myseq[j++]=arr[i]                    # add this new letter to our merged substring
              }

END           { print_seq() }                               # print last substring

' input.txt
```

The above generates:

```
chr1    196308345   196308372   tcttttcagtgtctttagatgtgtact,
chr1    63095765    63095791    agcacatgattagaagctaccaatgccc,
chr2    63095768    63095789    ctaggcttacagaagtgagcc,
```

---

An alternative approach (for lines to be merged) would be to use the index differences to pull just the 'unseen' portion of the new 4th column string (eg, via a `substring()` function) and prepend/append to the previously seen 4th column string.